# Is there a YUI datatable after Render event?

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I have some javascript I want to do post-render for a YUI datatable, but I couldnt find anything in their API for this. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [renderEvent](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#event_renderEvent)